# How to mark soft wrap lines?

Tags: luatex, line-breaking

Is there a way to mark all lines which have been wrapped automatically (i.e. places where LuaTeX decided there needed to be a line break)?  Something like `\localrightbox` but which is only active at the end of a line where some text has been wrapped to the next?  In the following MWE, the hook arrow should not appear starting at the last line of the first paragraph (because the first paragraph ends on that line, because the second paragraph only needs one line, and because the third has hard line breaks at the end of every line).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\newenvironment{speech}%
    {%begin
        \Large
        \setlength{\parindent}{-1cm}
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{1cm}
        \localrightbox{$\hookleftarrow$}
    }
    {%end
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{speech}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Sed faucibus, sem vel suscipit eleifend, ipsum dolor tempus nunc, ut iaculis nibh arcu vitae tortor.
Pellentesque a efficitur lectus, eget sagittis lorem.
Fusce vestibulum feugiat nibh, pulvinar convallis eros sagittis ac.
Pellentesque aliquam arcu a augue malesuada, sit amet eleifend orci vulputate.
Sed nibh dolor, commodo vel risus quis, elementum consequat dui.
Pellentesque eu neque eleifend, tincidunt mauris id, ultricies odio.

Aenean ac nisi congue, mollis leo a, cursus dolor.

Aenean non justo felis.\\
Cras interdum quam eu metus imperdiet ultricies.\\
Fusce finibus pellentesque volutpat.\\
Praesent id lacus eget dui ullamcorper finibus nec nec urna.\\
Quisque vel vestibulum quam.\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
Mauris vel nisl eros.\\
\end{speech}
\end{document}
```

If you compile this MWE, you'll see the hook arrow at the end of every line.  Ideally, the above should look like this:
[image: What I want the document to look like.]

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking for.  Perhaps you should mock up a document that will output a file as you would like.  I'm not asking for the impossible: answering your own question.  But you certainly can create an output document with the desired appearance as if all the *markup* had been done, not by hand, but automatically by LaTeX.  Do you get what I'm saying?

Comment: @A.Ellett I've edited in an image of the desired result for the MWE.

Comment: Off-topic: The `latexsym` package is quite obsolete; use `amssymb` instead. In case you're curious: These days, the only reasonable justification for loading the `latexsym` package is if the LaTeX document must be compiled in LaTeX2.09 compatibility mode. LaTeX2e superseded LaTeX2.09 in 1994 -- nearly 25 years ago! For sure, I can think of no valid reason for wishing to compile a LuaLaTeX document in LaTeX2.09 compatibility mode.

Comment: @Mico, Thanks.  I'll make that switch.  I used latexsym simply because it was the first package I found that provided the symbol I wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have come up with a solution which hooks into the `post_linebreak_filter`.  The code loops over all the lines in the paragraph, except for the last line, because the last line cannot be broken (otherwise it wouldn't be the last line).  For each line I iterate over all penalties within that line.  If there is a penalty with subtype 0 (userpenalty) that indicates that the user inserted a penalty by hand, as is the case for `\\`.  Then we only need to check that the value of the penalty is `-10000` and therefore a forced line break.  If that is not the case, then this means that there was no forced break and TeX broke the line by itself.  Hence we can insert the arrow at the end of the line.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newenvironment{speech}%
{%begin
  \Large
  \setlength{\parindent}{-1cm}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{1cm}%
  \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",
                                        mark_small_glue_lines, "speech")}%
}
{%
  \par % trigger the last post_linebreak_filter before disabling it
  \directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback("post_linebreak_filter", "speech")}%
}

\newbox\hookleftarrowbox
\setbox\hookleftarrowbox=\hbox{$\hookleftarrow$}
\directlua{
```

```lua
mark_small_glue_lines = function(head)
    local last_line = nil
    for line in node.traverse_id(node.id("hlist"), head) do
        if last_line then
            local has_userpenalty = false
            for pen in node.traverse_id(node.id("penalty"), last_line.list) do
                if not has_userpenalty then
                    has_userpenalty = (pen.subtype == 0 and pen.penalty == -10000)
                else
                    break
                end
            end
            if not has_userpenalty then
                node.insert_after(last_line.list, node.tail(last_line.list),
                                  node.copy(tex.box.hookleftarrowbox))
            end
        end
        last_line = line
    end
    return head
end
```

```
}
\begin{document}

\begin{speech}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Sed faucibus, sem vel suscipit eleifend, ipsum dolor tempus nunc, ut iaculis nibh
arcu vitae tortor.
Pellentesque a efficitur lectus, eget sagittis lorem.
Fusce vestibulum feugiat nibh, pulvinar convallis eros sagittis ac.
Pellentesque aliquam arcu a augue malesuada, sit amet eleifend orci vulputate.
Sed nibh dolor, commodo vel risus quis, elementum consequat dui.
Pellentesque eu neque eleifend, tincidunt mauris id, ultricies odio.

Aenean ac nisi congue, mollis leo a, cursus dolor.

Aenean non justo felis.\\
Cras interdum quam eu metus imperdiet ultricies.\\
Fusce finibus pellentesque volutpat.\\
Praesent id lacus eget dui ullamcorper finibus nec nec urna.\\
Quisque vel vestibulum quam.\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
Mauris vel nisl eros.
\end{speech}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow.  I was wondering what I could put together.  I've worked with LuaTeX, maybe that's something I should look into.

Comment: @A.Ellett I actually came up with a much better solution now.